# Is not a Enclosing class in Android while I call async class of class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Actually when i call Async class of class from my MainActivity i got Error("**Is not a Enclosing class**") and tried hard as possible but unable to short out this problem

**MainActivity Code :**

```
 Button listview=(Button)findViewById(R.id.inListView);
        listview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            String Restaurant = "restaurant";
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("onClick", "Button is Clicked");

                String url = getUrl(latitude, longitude, Restaurant);
                Object[] DataTransfer = new Object[2];
                DataTransfer[0] = mMap;
                DataTransfer[1] = url;
                Log.d("onClick", url);
                listviewActivity.GetNearbyPlaceData getNearbyPlacesListdata = new listviewActivity.GetNearbyPlaceData();
                getNearbyPlacesListdata.execute(DataTransfer);
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"Nearby Restaurants", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
```

**AsyncTask Code:**

```
public class listviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> placesListItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    // KEY Strings

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        // Getting listview
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    }


    private void ShowNearbyPlaces(List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList) {
        placesListItems.add((HashMap<String, String>) nearbyPlacesList);
        // list adapter
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(listviewActivity.this, placesListItems,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { KEY_REFERENCE, KEY_NAME}, new int[] {
                R.id.reference, R.id.name });

        // Adding data into listview
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    public class GetNearbyPlaceData extends AsyncTask<Object, String, String> {
        private GoogleMap mMap;
        private String url;
        private String googlePlacesData;


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
            try {
                Log.d("GetNearbyPlacesData", "doInBackground entered");
                mMap = (GoogleMap) params[0];
                url = (String) params[1];
                DownloadUrl downloadUrl = new DownloadUrl();
                googlePlacesData = downloadUrl.readUrl(url);
                Log.d("GooglePlacesReadTask", "doInBackground Exit");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("GooglePlacesReadTask", e.toString());
            }
            return googlePlacesData;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Log.d("GooglePlacesReadTask", "onPostExecute Entered");
            List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList = null;
            DataParser dataParser = new DataParser();
            nearbyPlacesList =  dataParser.parse(result);
            ShowNearbyPlaces(nearbyPlacesList);
            Log.d("GooglePlacesReadTask", "onPostExecute Exit");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to make `GetNearbyPlaceData` `static` to be able to be accessed like that.

Comment: yes but new problem is arise like **ShowNearbyPlaces** needs to be static and after that on Activity context error is shown **cannot be referenced from a static context**

Comment: Of course...thats why I didn't post it as an answer! Your code needs serious refactoring...Why are you calling an instance method `private void ShowNearbyPlaces()` from another activity (via `AsyncTask`) and why are you passing your entire map object to an inner class of another activity? Maybe, make the `AsyncTask` its own class (a helper class).

Comment: ohhh So it's means i have to create a another AsyncTask Class and then pass data for listview AsyncTask to customList Adapter class...

Comment: I just noticed...[as I understand] your map is in one activity and you have a listview in another activity... you need to process map data and show it in listview activity...Here *one* of the ways is that you can process the data within your map activity only and then pass the result (i guess `googlePlacesData` here) to the map activity via intent which will then parse it and show it in listview

Answer (score 0):

Your "GetNearbyPlaceData" is an inner class, which means it can only exist in the context of an instance of the outer class ("listviewActivity" in this case). To instantiate it you would need an instance of the activity, which is not recommended.
Either move the GetNearbyPlaceData to the class where you use it, move it to it's own file, or make it static.